# Typescript decorators with inheritance

Tags: typescript, inheritance, decorator

I am playing around with Typescript decorators and they seem to behave quite differently than what I'd expect when used alongside with class inheritance.

Suppose I have the following code:

```
class A {
    @f()
    propA;
}

class B extends A {
    @f()
    propB;
}

class C extends A {
    @f()
    propC;
}

function f() {
    return (target, key) => {
        if (!target.test) target.test = [];
        target.test.push(key);
    };
}

let b = new B();
let c = new C();

console.log(b['test'], c['test']);
```

Which outputs:

```
[ 'propA', 'propB', 'propC' ] [ 'propA', 'propB', 'propC' ]
```

Though I'd expect this:

```
[ 'propA', 'propB' ] [ 'propA', 'propC' ]
```

So, it seems that `target.test` is shared between A, B and C. And my understanding of what is going on here is as follow:

1. Since B extends A, `new B()` triggers the instantiation of A first, which triggers the evaluation of `f` for A. Since `target.test` is undefined, it is initialized.
2. `f` is then evaluated for B, and since it extends A, A is instantiated first. So, at that time, `target.test` (`target` being B) references `test` defined for A. So, we push `propB` in it. At this point, things go as expected.
3. Same as step 2, but for C. This time, when C evaluates the decorator, I would expect it to have a new object for `test`, different than that defined for B. But the log proves me wrong.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening (1) and how would I implement `f` such that A and B have separate `test` properties ?

I guess you'd call that an "instance specific" decorator ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alright, so after spending a few hours playing around and searching the web, I got a working version. I don't understand why this is working, so please forgive the lack of explanation.

The key is to use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, 'test') == null` instead of `!target.test` for checking the presence the `test` property.

If you use:

```
function f() {
    return (target, key) => {
        if (Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, 'test') == null) target.test = [];
        target.test.push(key);
    };
}
```

the console will show:

```
[ 'propB' ] [ 'propC' ]
```

Which is almost what I want. Now, the array is specific to each instance. But this means that `'propA'` is missing from the array, since it is defined in A. Hence we need to access the parent target and get the property from there. That took me a while to figure out, but you can get it with `Object.getPrototypeOf(target)`.

The final solution is:

```
function f() {
    return (target, key) => {
        if (Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, 'test') == null) target.test = [];
        target.test.push(key);

        /*
         * Since target is now specific to, append properties defined in parent.
         */
        let parentTarget = Object.getPrototypeOf(target);
        let parentData = parentTarget.test;
        if (parentData) {
            parentData.forEach(val => {
                if (target.test.find(v => v == val) == null) target.test.push(val);
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Which outputs

```
[ 'propB', 'propA' ] [ 'propC', 'propA' ]
```

May anyone that understands why this works while the above doesn't enlighten me.

Answer (score 6):

Your code has that behavior because your decorated field is a instance member, The `target` you received is the prototype of the class. When execution starts, class `A` will be loaded first as it is the parent class. So the `test` array is set on class A's `prototype`, which is shared by all Child Classes *B/C*. Hence you see 3 elements in the `test` array.

Instead of using `getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`, One alternative is to register the meta on the `target.constructor` which is the class itself. Then each class will hold its own metadata, on gathering decorated field, you just need to search up to the prototype chain and gather them all. (using the standard `relect-metadata` as helper).

```js
function f() {
  return (target, key) => {
    if (!Reflect.hasOwnMetadata('MySpecialKey', target.constructor)) {
      // put field list on the class.
      Reflect.defineMetadata('MySpecialKey', [], target.constructor);
    }
    Reflect.getOwnMetadata('MySpecialKey', target.constructor).push(key);
  };
}

  /**
   * @param clz the class/constructor
   * @returns the fields decorated with @f all the way up the prototype chain.
   */
  static getAllFields(clz: Record<string, any>): string[] {
    if(!clz) return [];
    const fields: string[] | undefined = Reflect.getMetadata('MySpecialKey', clz);
    // get `__proto__` and (recursively) all parent classes
    const rs = new Set([...(fields || []), ...this.getAllFields(Object.getPrototypeOf(clz))]);
    return Array.from(rs);
  }
```

Another option is using the class-validator way that having a global metadata storage which contains all the decorator related info. On executing logic, check if [the target constructor is instanceof the registered target](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/blob/develop/src/metadata/MetadataStorage.ts#L109). if so include the field.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It ended two full clock rounds of headache and helped me understand what I got wrong the entire time.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's becouse when class B is created prototype of A is copied with all it's custom properties (as references).

I used slightly modified solution, seams to solve more natural problem with duplicates if class C would not have any decorators.

Still not sure if this is the best way to handle such cases:

```
    function foo(target, key) {
        let
            ctor = target.constructor;

        if (!Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ctor, "props")) {
            if (ctor.props)
                ctor.props = [...ctor.props];
            else
                ctor.props = [];
        }

        ctor.props.push(key);
    }

    abstract class A {
        @foo
        propA = 0;
    }

    class B extends A {
        @foo
        propB = 0;
    }

    class C extends A {
        @foo
        propC = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@user5365075 I ran into the exact same issue when working with method decorators, and your fix worked.

Here is a decorator I am using in one of my packages (with an object instead of an array):

```
export function property(options) {
    return (target, name) => {
        // Note: This is a workaround due to a similar bug described here:
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43912168/typescript-decorators-with-inheritance

        if (!Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, '_sqtMetadata')) {
            target._sqtMetadata = {}
        }

        if (target._sqtMetadata.properties) {
            target._sqtMetadata.properties[name] = options.type
        } else {
            target._sqtMetadata.properties = { [name]: options.type }
        }

        const parentTarget = Object.getPrototypeOf(target)
        const parentData = parentTarget._sqtMetadata

        if (parentData) {
            if (parentData.properties) {
                Object.keys(parentData.properties).forEach((key) => {
                    if (!target._sqtMetadata.properties[key]) {
                        target._sqtMetadata.properties[key] = parentData.properties[key]
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can confirm the same behavior exists for class decorators as well.